# Слово "папоротник"

Tags: этимология

Я тоже хочу задать вопрос по этимологии. Меня интересует слово "папоротник". Русское ли оно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Древнерусское – папороть (поросль, заросль).
Индийское – parnam (перо, крыло).
В русском языке слово «папортник» употреблялось еще во времен язычества.
У древних славян существовало утраченное ныне слово «пороть», означавшее «парить, перо». От этого слова произошло и слово «папортник» – растение получило свое название из-за того, что его листья похожи на птичье перо.
Родственными являются:
украинское – папороть;
белорусское – папараць;
болгарское и сербохорватское – папрат.